# Best way to find the maximum sum of multiple arrays given constraints on index

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

Say I have 3 sorted arrays each of length 4, and I want to choose an index from each array such that the sum of the indexes are equal to 4. How would I find the maximum possible sum without testing all possible choices?

For instance I have the following arrays

```
1 : [0,0,0,8]
2 : [1,4,5,6]
3 : [1,5,5,5]

Then the solution would be 3,0,1. Because 3 + 0 + 1 = 4 and 8 + 1 + 5 is 
the maximum combination where the sum of the indexes are 4.
```

I need a solution that can be generalized to n arrays of size m where the sum of the indexes could equal anything.

For instance, it could be asked that this be solved with 1000 arrays all of size 1000 where the sum of the index is 2000.

If there is a python package somewhere that does this please let me know.

Comment: I see that you've tagged optimization as well. How quickly do you want this algorithm to run?

Answer (score 1):

This will achieve it , no sure the speed is meet your requirement

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0,8],[1,4,5,6],[1,5,5,5]])
import functools    
df=pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product([0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3])))
df=df.loc[df.sum(1)<=4,:]
df.index=df.apply(tuple,1)
df.apply(lambda x : df1.lookup(df.columns.tolist(),list(x.name)),1).sum(1).idxmax()


Out[751]: (3, 0, 1)

df.apply(lambda x : df1.lookup(df.columns.tolist(),list(x.name)),1).sum(1).max()
Out[752]: 14
```